# Overflow content outside of HTML Frame Element

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to make content overflow outside of a HTML `frame` element?

For example can I have a video that sits inside 1 `frame` extend beyond the extents of the frame?
[image]

I've tried making the `frame` have an `overflow` value of `visible`. And giving the video (`iframe`) element a `x` value of `-100px` but the video never moves further left than `0px`.

Any ideas how I could make the video overflow into the left frame using HTML, CSS or Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Are they actual frames within a frameset? If so, I don't think it's possible.

I would suggest not using frames. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/15938545/694325 for reasons why not to use frames.

Comment: Even if it's an iframe instead of frame it's still not possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176572

Comment: How about making images/videos as thumbnails and then using some kind of popup window? I would otherwise say Lightbox, but I don't think it's possible when viewed in a frame.

Answer (score 0):

From the outset I would say its not possible. But, a quick 'Google' and I came accross this article - http://forums.creativecow.net/thread/16/856267 which hints at a possible solution using the `top.document` javascript selector.

This stackoverflow question also provides a possible solution - [Absolute div overlay iframe borders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840475/absolute-div-overlay-iframe-borders)