# Popup inside iframe not show up on parent page

Tags: javascript, html, popup, embed

I have a problem when I embed my second site to my first site. In my second site there are a `popup` and it triggered with a `button`. I sucessfully embed it with `<embed>` tag and I set `width` in `800px` and `height` in `300px`. When I hit the button the `popup` showing but just inside the `800px x 300px` frame. I want to show the `popup` in parent page which is my first site. I use this code to embed it.

```
<embed src="http://example.com" width=800 height=300 />
```

How to show my `popup` in parent page so the `popup` will look full in screen and not just inside the frame ? Thank you before.

Comment: Technically you can't do this. The `iframe` is like a browser within your website. Just like you can't overflow the contents of your website outside of the browser window, you can't overflow it outside the iframe either. However, there are certain tricks that might make it possible. More on that can be found the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840475/absolute-div-overlay-iframe-borders

Comment: @icecub I understand if that link told about hijacking the `iframe`. But, do you have another solutions without `iframe` which can be use to solve my problems ? In this case I will use any way to make my popup showing in parent page. Thanks.